# .Net Core Razor Page DropDownList with ADO.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using .Net Core Razor Pages with ADO.Net. I am trying to pull data from a database and insert into a dropdownlist. I am getting this this

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<IntranetSite.Models.CommDept>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

CommDept Model

```
[Table("CommDept")]
public class CommDept
{
    [Key]
    public int CommDeptID { get; set; }
    public string DeptText { get; set; }
    public SelectList DropDownList { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
[BindProperty]
public List<CommDept> DropDownList { set; get; }

public void OnGet()
{
    var DropDownList = new List<CommDept>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT CommDeptID, DeptText FROM CommDept", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                DropDownList.Add(new CommDept
                {
                    CommDeptID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr.GetString(0)),
                    DeptText = rdr.GetString(1)
                });
            }
        }
    }

    var adjList = new CommDept();
    adjList.DropDownList = new SelectList(DropDownList, "CommDeptID", "DeptText");
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
    <select class="form-control rounded" asp-items="Model.DropDownList"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, try using an explicit type cast:

```
DropDownList.Add((SelectListItem)new CommDept
{
    CommDeptID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr.GetString(0)),
    DeptText = rdr.GetString(1)
});
```

If that does not work, then either you'll have to [write a custom Type converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) on your class CommDept, or use `new SelectListItem { Value = ..., Text = ... }` directly.

Comment: I get this error Cannot convert type 'IntranetSite.Models.CommDept' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem'

Comment: Then you'll either have to [write a custom Type converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) on class CommDept, or use `new SelectListItem { Value = ..., Text = ... }` directly.

Comment: Can you give me an example?